# Linux server related issues

Tags: linux

My home directory has to unknown user SYS-Snap and Virtfs using lot of space and my centos server running 92% disk uses can I delete it ?please suggest me ..

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using cPanel on your server and it's NOT safe to remove virtfs directory:

root# cat /home/virtfs/0_README_BEFORE_DELETING_VIRTFS

The /home/virtfs directory contains critical operating system files. If you
remove /home/virtfs, or any directories under /home/virtfs, you will cause
irreparable damage to your operating system. Do not remove /home/virtfs, or any
directories under /home/virtfs, unless you have tested, up-to-date backups.

You should ignore any disk usage warnings you receive that are associated with
the /home/virtfs directory!

For more information about the /home/virtfs directory, visit the documentation
at http://go.cpanel.net/virtfsdoc